# angularjs routing / html5mode and htaccess giving 404 error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, apache, .htaccess

I am building my first angularjs app in 1.6x and my router is resulting in a 404 errors

my router looks like this:

```
app.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    $routeProvider
    .when('/account', {
        templateUrl: 'views/account/welcome.html',
    }) //works
    .when('/account/emails', {
        templateUrl: 'views/account/email.html', 
        controller: 'emailController'
    }) //404 error
    .when('/account/wallet', {
        templateUrl: 'views/account/wallet.html',
    }) //404 error
    .when('/account/settings', {
        templateUrl: 'views/account/settings.html',
    }) //404 error
    .when('/account/logout', {
        templateUrl: 'views/account/logout.html',
    }) //404 error
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
    }) //works
});
```

and my htaccess looks like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine On 
    Options FollowSymLinks
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /#/$1 [L]

</ifModule>
```

So my router works correctly within the app, but if my browser address is at say `//localhost/account/emails`or a similar path and I refresh the page, I get a 404 error. This also happens when I address the path directly from the browser.

`//localhost/` and `//localhost/account` work because the are actual paths in the apps file system with respective index.html files. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

You have wrong `RewriteRule` in your `.htaccess`. You want to use HTML5 mode, so your URLs will not be prefixed with `/#/` anymore.

This could work:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/account.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*) /account/index.html [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^(.*) /index.html [NC,L]
```

Comment: //localhost/account/emails when I try to access this path directly still gives me a 404 with this :(

Comment: Have you tried the latest version, with `RewriteRule ^(.*) /index.html [NC,L]`? Is your `index.html` in root (`localhost/index.html`)?

Comment: Yes I replaced mine with your entire code block. There is an index.html in the root and /account directories

Comment: Why do you have 2 index files? Maybe you should route to `/account/index.html` instead...

Comment: because the root directory hosts the sites main pages, while the /account directory holds the files for the user account that will be logged in. I guess two separate applications is the best way to explain it.

Comment: Ok than you need to rewrite rules for each index file I guess

Comment: still a 404 for the angular created paths

Comment: You will need to debug this with apache error.log then. The problem is definitely there.

Comment: [Sun Oct 29 16:50:03.494193 2017] [core:alert] [pid 57] [client ::1:10029] /var/www/html/june_frontend/.htaccess: Invalid command 'RewriteEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration, referer: http://localhost/

Comment: So you do not have mod_rewrite enabled at all... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/869092/how-to-enable-mod-rewrite-for-apache-2-2